# How to understand / be aware of Ubuntu bug fixes?

Tags: 12.04, updates

Where can I follow non-technical release notes on Ubuntu bug fixes? The notes in `Updates available` are quite abstruse to me, while I do want to know whether there will be bug fix for things like Suspend in Ubuntu 12.04.

An example for comparison is whenever there's a major bug in Windows / Apple (e.g. recent Macbook Air's camera malfunction), the tech news is all over it and when there's a bug fix come out, it's very easy for me to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have something similar to that , named as changelog. There we will notice what are the changes in the update of the application we have done and those included whats the bug and its token with its foxed/not information.

```
   apt-get changelog <application_name>
```

For example: `apt-get chanelog firefox`

```
firefox (25.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.13.10.1) saucy-security; urgency=low

  * New upstream stable release (FIREFOX_25_0_1_BUILD1)
    - see LP: #1251576 for USN information

 -- Chris Coulson <chris.coulson@canonical.com>  Fri, 15 Nov 2013 10:27:58 +0000

firefox (25.0+build3-0ubuntu0.13.10.1) saucy-security; urgency=low

  * New upstream stable release (FIREFOX_25_0_BUILD3)
    - see LP: #1245414 for USN information
```

Comment: Is that the change log included whenever I install updates? Those aren't very illuminating to end-users I have to say. May that means I just have to learn more about Linux -- but speaking as a newbie who's struggled with ubuntu hardware compatibility, I hope there's more layman coverage on this issue.

Comment: yes If you install an application then changelog will be included. look at the answer for the command.